# prefix field with letters

Tags: sql-server

I've been given the task of combining 7 `databases` into one legacy system that will only hold static data.

So what I want to do is add a prefix of two letters to the identity field of each `table` so that I can see by the `ID` of which `database` it originally came from e.g.

`StaffID = 1` in the old database, in the new single `database` I want it to look like this `StaffID = AB1`. This is also to get rid of the problem of users in all seven databases having the same `StaffID` (Along with other ID Fields).

Is there a quick and easy way of doing this? Or do you guys think there is a better solution?

Cheers!

Comment: why in the same field ? The new db has to have the same structure ? Or you can add another field, where you can specify "original table - db" or something like that ?

Comment: @user1563397 - Did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and easy; not really.  If you want to update the existing IDs, instead of creating a new column to refer to:

- First, you'll need to change any ID fields that are numeric (`int`, etc.) into a `varchar` field to hold the new key.  The `varchar` would need to be of an appropriate size to hold the largest ID plus the prefix.
- You would also need to convert any foreign key fields from a numeric field to a varchar field of an appropriate size.
- Finally, you would need to import the data into the new database, appending the prefix to any primary keys and foreign keys.